# Copy several assets in one layer

Tags: linux, docker

I want to do this:

```
COPY src/ public/ config-overrides.js /usr/src/app/
```

But I have learnt the hard way that this actually means:

```
COPY src/* public/* config-overrides.js /usr/src/app/
```

Which is not at all what I want.

I can hack this via a `.dockerignore`, but I do not like that solution because:

- if a new file is added to the repo, it needs to be added to the `.dockerignore` too.
- I like to explicitly list the dependencies in my `Dockerfile`

How can I copy an explicit list of files and directories (not just the contents) in a single layer?

Am I simply SOL?

Answer (score 0):

You can reorganize the repo:

```
app
+-- src
+-- public
\-- config-overrides.js
```

And then you would just

```
COPY app/ /usr/src/app/
```

---

Another option is to go with a multi-stage build:

```
FROM scratch as app
COPY src/ /usr/src/app/ 
COPY public/ /usr/src/app/ 
COPY config-overrides.js /usr/src/app/ 

FROM your_base
COPY --from=app /usr/src/app/ /usr/src/app/
```

---

Otherwise, keep it 3 separate layers. The added overhead of an additional layer is really minimal. The times you want to merge layers are when you get dozens of layers, if you have the same file in multiple layers and would overwrite it, or you change/delete a file that was created in a previous layer.